# What is the advantage of following the reading of the Megilla out of a scroll?

Tags: megillat-esther

The halakha is that the reader of the Megilla needs to read from a kosher scroll. **But what is the advantage of following the reading out a scroll?**

I see [here](http://www.aish.com/h/pur/m/48970631.html) in the name of the Pri Megadim that "*where possible, it is preferable for those listening to have their own kosher Megillah to follow from*". Why is that?

Kitzur Schulchan Aruch ([141:13](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur141.html)) says "*in any case, it is proper and correct that each individual has a kosher Megillah so that one can say by oneself word by word quietly in case he did not hear (any) one word from the reader*". Is that the reason?

Or is it *hiddur mitzva* (beautification the mitzva)?

Comment: May be that it helps to listening the words and enhance concentration.

Comment: I understood it to be that if one misses a word, the individual can read the word himself from a kosher scroll to ensure having heard the entire megillah from a proper scroll.

Comment: @Danno But you can read up to half the _megila_ from memory and reading from a _chumash_ shouldn't be worse than reading from memory.

Comment: @Daniel yes, but who knows going in how much one will have to read on his own?

Comment: @Danno If you are reading more than half of the _megilla_, I wouldn't call that "following the reading." I'd call that "reading the _megilla_."

Comment: @Daniel I see it as all in the planning One has a kosher megilla to follow along in, but if it ends up that he needs to read words himself, up to any amount, he is covered. I would rather that than using a book and following along until I realize that I have had to repeat over half the text, and then scrambling to find a kosher megilla and starting over.

Comment: @Danno, it seems you have an answer to post….

Comment: @msh210 it is just unsourced, personal sense. The answer seems to be in the kitzur quote in the question

Comment: @Daniel What makes you think doing so is lechatchila? Clearly the reader is supposed to try and have a Kosher Megillah to read from. Otherwise we could start selling half Megillas for cheaper and only have to prep half the leining.

Comment: that's not a very precise summary of the peri megadim... http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3197

Comment: @ Double AA Althouh I understood your comment to be somewhat in jest, I still must correct you from a halachic point of view. Although Bdieved if one read less than half the Megilla by heart he is still yotzeh, and reading the whole Megilla from the text is only lechatchila, this is only true if the  megilla which he is reading from is a complete Megilla. It is wrong to say that even if it is only a (somewhat more than) "half megilla" would be kosher B'dieved.